# Using regex for a specific element of a nested list of tuples

Tags: python, regex

I have nested list of tuples:

```
ntl = [('h', '2019-11-12', 'l'), 
       ('h', '2019-11-11', 'm'),
      ]
```

As you can see the entry at index 1 in every tuple is a date.
I want to remove the hyphens between the numbers.
Like this:

```
date = [('h', '20191112', 'l'), 
       ('h', '20191111', 'm'),
       ]
```

I tried something like this:

```
date = [re.sub(r'-', '', i[1]) for i in ntp]
```

But this outputs just the date entry and not the other two tuple entries.

Can somebody help?

Comment: _But this outputs just the date entry and not the other two tuple entries._ That's to be expected though, no? Your list comprehension contains just `re.sub(r'-', '', i[1])`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is something like it fine for you ?

```py
date = [(i[0], re.sub(r'-', '', i[1]), i[2]) for i in ntp]
>>> [('h', '20191112', 'l'), ('h', '20191111', 'm')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the unpacking differently

```
[(i, re.sub(r'-', '', j), k) for i,j,k in ntl]
```

`[('h', '20191112', 'l'), ('h', '20191111', 'm')]`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to build your list of tuples more explicitly:

```
date = [ (i[0], re.sub(r'-', '', i[1], i[2]) for i in ntp]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `re.sub`, you can split the date string and join again:

```py
date = [(a, ''.join(b.split('-')), c) for a, b, c in ntl]
```

Comment: or using `str.replace` to remove the '-': `date = [(a, b.replace('-', ''), c) for a, b, c in ntl]`

Comment: @Paul potato potato xD

Answer (score 1):

You can use string `replace` method instead of `re.sub`:

```
date = [(a, d.replace("-", ""), c) for a, d, c in ntl]
```